# Lift JsonResponse Backslashed string

Tags: json, scala, rest, mongodb, lift

all!

I am trying to create Rest web service with Lift and Scala, which gets results from MOngoDB with map reduce functions. So for example this is my service function:

```
val map ="""function map(){ 
 filteredDur= [];
 this."""+sendername+""".forEach(function (s){
  if (s.start > new ISODate(""""+ timestamp +""":00.00+02:00")){
    filteredDur.push(s);
  }
 });
 filteredDur.sort(function(a,b) {
   return a.start-b.start
 })
 emit(this._id, {After: filteredDur});
}"""

 val reduce = "function(key, values) { return values[0]; }"
 val mr = MapReduceCommand(mongoColl.getName(), map, reduce, MapReduceInlineOutput, None,  None, None, None)
 val result = mongoColl.mapReduce(mr)
 var temp = result.toString()
   //here some transformations of map_reduce result like getting read of map_reduce      //comments
 return JString(temp);

serve { //this are Lift's RestHelper methods
 case Req("sendungen" :: "sendungen" ::Nil, suffix,  GetRequest) => getAllSendungen()
}
```

I am using RestHelper in Lift. the problem is I don't get a valid JSON :( I get all quotes backslashed. result:

```
{ \"desc\" : \"\" , \"duration\" : 30 , \"start\" : { \"$date\" : \"2010-07-13T09:30:00Z\"} , \"end\" : { \"$date\" : \"2010-07-13T10:00:00Z\"}
```

and my client parser doesn't parse this. so I want:

```
{ "desc" : "" , "duration" : 30 , "start" : { "$date" : "2010-07-13T09:30:00Z"}
```

How can I make this work? I know I can replace slashes in client application, but i don't think this is very elegant. I tried using case classes, but got the same. here is case class:

```
 case class Sendung(duration:Int, subtitle:String, desc:String,  image:String,       sender:String,end:java.util.Date, title:String, start:java.util.Date) {

  def toJSON (e : Sendung) : JObject = {
  import net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL._
  import net.liftweb.json.JsonAST._
   ("key" ->
   ("duration" -> JInt(duration))) ~
   ("subtitle" -> subtitle) ~
   ("desc" -> desc));
  }

 }
```

Comment: how about you format your code?

Comment: sorry, these scale's multiple quotes are messing everything up :(

Answer (score 1):

Solved: 
    JsonResponse.apply(net.liftweb.json.JsonParser.parse(result_string))

returns LiftResponse with non-backslashed. unfortunately, JString doesn't have an option of triple quotes. that is why it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

We were running into a similar problem on our project -- we needed to return JSON through a JsonResponse object. It was actually as simple as doing:

```
val json = ("userId" -> userId) ~ ("userToken" -> userToken)
JsonResponse(json)
```

With that you get nice, unescaped JSON in the response. Your client-side parser should be able to work that.

Comment: I had a bit different situation. it was not recommended to use attribute names implicitly. they could change. but thank you for response anyway! ;)